# Admob interestitial causes app to close

Tags: android, admob, ondestroy

I'm trying to integrate Admob interstitial ads to my android app and for some reason. Every time I open an ad it calls my activity onDestroy method witch results on my app being closed without any log-cat errors or messages.

Does anyone knows what may be causing my app to close once Admob interstitial is opened ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android closes processes if needed when an application enters the background.  You need to be able to handle the destruction of the activity.  Look into saving instance states [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151777/saving-activity-state-in-android)